# Create equal-width div's with CSS

Tags: css, layout

I have a div with a certain width and within this `parent` div I would like to place one or more 'child' divs.  I would like them to be placed next to each other (so I'm using either `float:left` or `display:inline-block`) and I want them to all be the same width.  I pretty much want them to fill the parent div (so if I have 4 divs they should each be 25% width, if 5 20% width etc) with a certain max-width.  They key here is that it should work no matter the number of divs - could be 1, could be 5 could be 15.

I have tried doing this in the following jsFiddle, but I can't figure out how to make it work without any JavaScript.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ8as/10/)

I guess my problem is that divs usually expand to the width of their content where I want them to expand to fit the parent?  I can try width:100% on all the child divs, but it doesn't seem like this plays too well with `float:left` or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Is the number of divs going to change? Or is the width of the parent div dynamic?

Comment: Yeah the number of divs is going to change.  The width of parent is fixed.

Comment: How is the number of divs going to change? Will javascript add and remove them, or are they generated (and subsequently fixed in number) when the page is generated?

Comment: Both.  When the page is created I might have 3 or 5 or 10 divs.  Then later on more might be added with JavaScript.  But I'll settle for a solution which just works for any number of divs (so adding more with JavaScript isn't the end of the world)

Comment: What is the actual content that you need to display on the page for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe make it as a `table`, and add all elements as `td` inside one `tr`. If you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858108/how-to-make-children-auto-fit-parents-width-only-with-css) is a jQuery Solution

**EDIT**

This is the only way I can think of using pure CSS, not sure if there is any other way

Also check this already existing question [Distribute elements evenly using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674045/distribute-elements-evenly-using-css) in SO

Comment: Agreed, tables are well-suited for this behaviour. Adding additional `<td>` elements with javascript will also not break the solution.

Answer (score 5):

The best option is `display:flex` for parent div and use `flex-basis:100%` in child div

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">6</div>
  <div class="flex-item">7</div>
  <div class="flex-item">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the use of `display: table;` would help? http://jsfiddle.net/g4dGz/119/

Answer (score 0):

What about: http://jsfiddle.net/TnCCd/

Borders add to width, and the overflow: hidden bit will clear the floats so the container doesn't collapse

Comment: But if I only have 3 divs they don't fill the parent at all?  http://jsfiddle.net/TnCCd/

Comment: this is fixed width, but what is needed id dynamic width

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this would easiest be achieved by using a table (although this is a swearword in these tableless-times). Not knowing what the elements is used for I don't know if this is semantically correct.

You could also try experimenting with display:table-cell etc. But that's less compatible with older browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to through this out there - you may be best off going with *gasp* TABLES (oh no what did he say! aaaaaaah!)

http://jsfiddle.net/taw57/

EDIT: My fiddle shows your broken div version with two table versions with differing numbers of columns.

Comment: Yeah seems like this is the way to go.  I'm gonna leave the question for a bit to see if someone comes up with a non-table answer.