# Making an unordered list span 100% the width of a div

Tags: css

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>First</l1>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>


div {
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

With CSS, is there a way to make the LI tags automatically fill the whole width of the parent div, evenly? So they'd each take up 25%.

Specifying 'width' as 25% would obviously work but it's not solution I'm after. The menu in question is dynamically created and new items are created and deleted at times.

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have three options:

1. Use JavaScript to calculate the sizes
2. Use a table, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674045/distribute-elements-evenly-using-css) (this is actually not a bad option — it’s pure HTML and CSS
3. If you’re only targeting new browsers, you can use the new [flexible box](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/) component of CSS (shown here with a couple of vendor prefixes):

   ```
   ul{
       padding: 0;
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: -moz-box;
       display: box;
   }
   li{
       list-style: none;
       list-style:none;
       text-align: center;
       -webkit-box-flex: 1;
       -moz-box-flex: 1;
       box-flex: 1;
   }
   ```

Comment: Dont forget to remove floats on the li if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li{
  display:block;
  width:25%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: My question stated that a percentage width in this case is not the solution I'm after.

Comment: otherwise you could give them fixed widths, if you know how wide the div would be, as it fits in some other element (with that 100% width)

Comment: I know it would work for a static menu. The menu I'm asking the question for has items added and deleted occasionally through a CMS therefore this is not the solution.

Comment: so, if you have three items, those three should fill the entire div, or if you have 5 and so on?

Comment: Yes. I have a solution written in jQuery because I couldn't think if it was possible purely with CSS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4244/discussion-between-beerwin-and-allanb)

Answer (score -1):

In my searches from a while back, I didn't come across anything that lets you dynamically specify the list item width.  If you're also asking how to have your list be horizontal instead of vertical, use:

```
li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I knew about the display inline rule. It was more a question of the width. Thanks